# CDN service for small student project (MMORPG)

Tags: cloud-storage, game

I'm looking for some feedbacks / recommendation for a way to deliver my project's content to our users.

### Description

I'm hosting a student project, a small MMORPG server that we are developing on our free time, I've got to plan our release and for that, I recently thought about the delivery of our client files.

### Requirements

We are supposed to delivery ~ 100MB of monthly patchs per user through our launcher.

These 100MB of monthly patchs are going to be redistributed over several players, the "low estimation" I made is around 500 monthly individual downloads.

Our users are based in Europe so we don't need a "cross region" content delivery.

### Already investigated solutions

What I already saw (good combination to limit expenses) :

- Load Balancing over several VPS

  - Difficult to maintain
  - Not easily maintainable (needs monitoring etc...)
  - DevOps with effort needed
- AWS S3 + AWS CloudFront

  - Easily maintainable (API / SDK / Infra as code)
  - Easy DevOps (Ansible / CI/CD)
  - 50GB of monthly storage + monthly bandwidth free tier
  - Can become expansive for a small student project (pay for what we use)
- GCP GCS + GCP Cloud CDN

  - Easily maintainable (API / SDK / Infra as Code)
  - Easy DevOps (Ansible / CI/CD)
  - 5GB of monthly storage + monthly bandwidth free tier
  - Can become expansive for a small student project (pay for what we use)
- DropBox

  - Easily maintainable (API / SDK)
  - Needs effort on DevOps
  - 20GB of monthly bandwidth limitation
  - Not the purpose of DropBox at all

Other CDNs I saw are more expansive or not easily usable without more development on our side (which is already difficult to handle, we are doing it on our free time and don't want to add more and more)

If anyone have suggestions or feedbacks about from experience, I would really appreciate :) !